# Read data -attribute as variable

Tags: jquery, html, variables, pool

I have these selection boxes made in HTML with data attributes. Now when somebody clicks one of those boxes i want Jquery to read out the data attribute and use it as a variable. Add 1 or minus 1 to or from a pool. However I'm getting a NaN error. Any ideas of fixing this? Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" class="selectable one" data="one" />Antwoord 1</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="selectable two" data="two" />Antwoord 2</label><br />
```

JQUERY:

```
one = 0;
two = 0;

$('.selectable').on('click', function(){
    // tell me what pool you are
var thispool = $(this).attr("data");
    // you are now activated
$(this).toggleClass('activated');
    //add +1 if activated, else -1
if ($(this).hasClass('activated')){thispool++;}
else {thispool--;}
});
```

Comment: because it is not a numerical value to do numerical operations

Comment: @Satpal look at the value it is `one` not `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can' refer a variable using another variable like that, instead you can use an object as given below

```
var counter = {
    one: 0,
    two: 0
}

$('.selectable').on('click', function () {
    // tell me what pool you are
    var thispool = $(this).attr("data");
    // you are now activated
    $(this).toggleClass('activated');
    //add +1 if activated, else -1
    if ($(this).hasClass('activated')) {
        counter[thispool]++;
    } else {
        counter[thispool]--;
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AR2Q3/)

Comment: what if there are more than one data-attributes on the HTML tag

Answer (score 2):

You need to assingn numeric value to `data` that is `1` not `one` and the two must be `2` to apply increament or decrement operator.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" class="selectable one" data="1" />Antwoord 1</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="selectable two" data="1" />Antwoord 2</label><br />
```